# SQL Select priority data from overlapping date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, with overlapping data (actual tables have more columns, but the key I need to remove overlaps from is date):
Let's call them:

HighPri

```
╔════════╦═══════╗
║  Date  ║ Value ║
╠════════╬═══════╣
║ Dec-19 ║     1 ║
║ Jan-20 ║     2 ║
║ Feb-20 ║     3 ║
╚════════╩═══════╝
```

and LoPri

```
╔════════╦═══════╗
║  Date  ║ Value ║
╠════════╬═══════╣
║ Jan-20 ║     5 ║
║ Feb-20 ║     6 ║
║ Mar-20 ║     7 ║
╚════════╩═══════╝
```

And I'm looking for a Sql Server query that would return this.  (preferentially High pri where there is overlap, ow LoPri):

```
╔════════╦═══════╗
║  Date  ║ Value ║
╠════════╬═══════╣
║ Dec-19 ║     1 ║
║ Jan-20 ║     2 ║
║ Feb-20 ║     3 ║
║ Mar-20 ║     7 ║
╚════════╩═══════╝
```

Looking for pure sql solution.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this as a `full join` with `coalesce()` for priorization:

```
select coalesce(h.date, l.date) as date,
       coalesce(h.value, l.value) as value
from highPri h full outer join
     lowPri l 
     on h.date = l.date;
```

Comment: So coalesce takes in the order given?

Comment: @Marc: yes - `coalesce()` returns its first non-`null` argument.